# What are the order 5 symmetries of the the torus knot T(3,4)?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, geometric-group-theory

Generally, I am interested in understanding the free actions of finite cyclic groups on $S^3$ which leave invariant an oriented torus knot $T(p,q)$. For a specific example, consider the knot $T(3,4)$ and the group $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. My understanding is that there is a unique (up to equivariant homoemorphism of pairs $(S^3,K)$) order 5 symmetry of each torus knot, see for example the top of page 2 [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Papers/knotspaces.pdf), since there is a unique order 5 subgroup of $S^1$. However, here are two free order 5 symmetries of $T(3,4)$, where $H$ is a right-handed half twist, $F^2$ is two right-handed full twists, $I$ is the trivial tangle, $-F$ is a left-handed full twist, and $T(3,4)$ is the closure of the shown braid:

[[image: A free order 5 symmetry given by sliding <span class=]$1/5$th of the way to the right, and then doing $1/5$th of a left-handed full twist." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flrju.png),

and

[[image: A free order 5 symmetry given by sliding <span class=]$1/5$th of the way to the right, and then doing $2/5$ths of a right-handed full twist." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gObYU.png).

It seems to me that in the first example the quotient of $S^3$ is the lens space $L(5,-1)$ and in the second example the quotient is the lens space $L(5,2)$. Since these 3-manifolds are not homeomorphic, there then could not be an equivariant homemomorphism of pairs $(S^3,T(3,4))$ between these two symmetries. This seems to contradict the uniqueness of the order 5 symmetry on $T(3,4)$.

Is there indeed a unique order 5 symmetry of $T(3,4)$? If so, up to what equivalence of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ symmetries? Can I see directly that these two symmetries are the same under that equivalence?

Comment: Your first paragraph seems a little confused to me.  You are citing a Hatcher paper on the homotopy-type of the space of embeddings $Emb(S^1, S^3)$ but you are trying to come to some conclusion about uniqueness of an order 5 symmetry.  Hatcher does not talk about this issue.  He does discuss the subgroup of $Isom(S^3) \simeq O_4$ that preserves a torus knot.  But that is quite different from studying finite subgroups of $Diff(S^4, K)$.  I think it would help to state your question clearly.

Comment: Are you asking if all element of order $5$ in $Diff(S^3, T_{3,4})$, are conjugate?

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly my confustion - do you know of a reference discussing finite order subgroups of $Diff(S^3,K)$ for torus knots? Indeed I am interested to know  how many conjugacy classes of order 5 elements there are.

Comment: For a torus knot (ignoring the unknot) $Diff(S^3, K)$ has the homotopy-type of $O_2$.  There are four elements of order $5$ in $O_2$.  The idea is to think of $O_2$ as the semi-direct product of $\{\pm 1\}$ with $SO_2$.  $SO_2$ has a unique subgroup with five elements, and four of them are generators.  If you allow conjugation from all of $O_2$, then there are two conjugacy classes.  But if you restrict to $SO_2$, then all four elements are distinct.

Comment: The theorem about the homotopy type of $Diff(S^3, K)$ follows from Hatcher and Ivanov's work on spaces of incompressible surfaces.  I believe Hatcher cites the result in the paper you are quoting in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused about something though - since there is a unique order 5 subgroup of $SO(2)$, the quotient of $S^3$ by this group should be some lens space (fixed for a specific torus knot), but I think my pair of examples for $T(4,3)$ have different quotients? Sorry for the incoherence; if I knew what I was confused about I would ask a clearer question.

Comment: How are you counting two different symmetries?   If I understand your example correctly, these two symmetries generate the same group of diffeomorphisms of $S^3$, so they have the same quotient.

Comment: In $S^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$, isn't the first one $(z,w) \mapsto (e^{2\pi i/5} \cdot z, e^{-2\pi i /5} \cdot w)$ so that the quotient is $L(5,-1) \cong L(5,1)$ and the second one $(z,w) \mapsto (e^{2\pi i/5} \cdot z, e^{4\pi i /5} \cdot w)$ so that the quotient is $L(5,2)$?

Comment: Those don't look like symmetries of $T_{4,3}$ to me.  For the torus knot in one of its standard embeddings the symmetries are $(z,w) \longmapsto (t^4 z, t^3 w)$ where $t$ is a unit complex number, i.e. I am describing the homomorphism from $S^1 \to SO_4$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll do some more reading and see if I can explain the symmetries I have in mind clearly / post a specific question later.